# finally, try catch block statement in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I dont understand why this code is wrong, what am I missing???

```
    try{
input = inputFile.readLine();

}

finally{
inputFile.close();
}
catch (IOException e){
    System.out.println("I/O error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: finally goes after catch.

Comment: put catch before finally

Comment: What they said, but also: Please describe the problem you are having when you post a question.

Comment: I think this is time to spend sometime on reading books or documentation than just typing in something and posting for help

Comment: Also whatever book you are reading, it always explains the concept if you read further, before posting your doubt here.

Answer (score 1):

finally should come after the catch block.

```
  try{}
  catch{}
  finaly
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this order

```
try 
{
  ...
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
   //Treat exception
}
finally 
{
  //Clean your ressources
}
```